# Find the Table ID name using DOM

Tags: html, dom, asp-classic

I have an HTML file with a table ID named: `results-table`. All i want is to identify the table in my loop searching. I have at least an example on how to identify the table using className.

Example of finding the table with ClassName:

```
For Each table In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    If table.className = "results-table" Then
            tablestr = table.outerHTML
    End If
Next
```

In this case, how could i be able to find the table using the table ID?

Comment: That code is not JavaScript and it's most definitely not using jQuery.

Comment: im sorry for the tags, anyhow all i need is a comparison statement like with the example above. if className is used for class attribute in html, what should I be used for ID attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('results-table');
```

or in your case, it looks like

`HTMLDoc.getElementById("results-table")` would work.

Comment: im getting errors while using it. it says "Object doesn't support this property or method" but when i use getElementsbyTagName, it works perfectly.